# Ebean and playframework

Tags: playframework, persistence, playframework-1.x, ebean

In play 2.0 Ebean should become the default persistence layer. And
after a few days of hibernate frustration I started a look on Ebean. I
found the yabe example really impressive.  However I had a bunch of
questions:

1. Does anybody use the [play-module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/ebean) in a commercial project?
2. Does the module works with play 1.2?
3. What databases-platforms are supported? I found a special-class for
   Hsql.
4. Is there any update-support for database-tables or is it always
   drop and create?

Would be great if any one can give some information about.

Answer (score 1):

On your questions:

1. I'm not aware of any famous application using it, but for what I saw it has a very active community that uses it. It's been around for 4 years (maybe more), so I expect some reliability :)
2. There seems to be a [module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/ebean), code [here](https://github.com/lyubo/play-ebean#readme), that should be compatible. Never tried it though
3. Supported DB include: Oracle, MySql, Postgres, H2, SQL Server, SQLite. Maybe mroe, but these should be enough
4. EBeans can generate DDL for the database Schema. And it would surprise me if it doesn't have a "update" procedure (it would limit the usefulness a lot!)

Comment: I assume too that ebean selves is reliable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349341/how-mature-is-ebean-or-siena). I'm unsure about the plugin. It looks like that no one (except the author) use it :-/

Comment: I used the plugin too (in 1.2.3) and it worked without a problem. Migrating from JPA is a bit tricky, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

- Does anybody use the play-module in a commercial project?

Not yet.

- Does the module works with play 1.2?

I've tried, it does not.

- What databases-platforms are supported? I found a special-class for Hsql.

All that ebean supports.

- Is there any update-support for database-tables or is it always drop and create?

Use the [liquibase module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/liquibase) for this.